# Add CCK field to panel / page (from page manager)

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, entities, panels, chaos-tool-suite

Working in a D6 site, I was asked to add the CCK field that appears in all nodes, which is a taxonomy term reference, a tag, to a "Landing Page" created using page manager and panels. Is that even possible? If yes, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I posted an answer, but since you don't state the purpose of the request, it's possible I don't understand what you are after.

Comment: you will have to create the cck field in all content type. you can choose the existing field from the list

Comment: The purpose of the request is rather self-explanatory. Since the "rest of the pages" can be tagged, the content manager team wants those "new page thingys" to be taggable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. Pages are not entities (or nodes in D6) and so cannot have fields, CCK or D7 core, on them.

It's possible that [FAPE](http://drupal.org/project/fape) does what you want, since it allows you to stick an `Entity` directly into a `Page`, but that's D7 only.